# Link lines across small multiple charts d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I am trying to get lines to change style on mouseover across multiple charts.  [In this example available here](http://blockbuilder.org/jalapic/6283b087a0dc28847fc5), I have two charts that both have five groups A,B,C,D,E.  Each however is in a different csv (I am open to bringing the data in one csv or as one json array, but this is just how I have it set up right now).

I can get two charts each with five lines corresponding to the group. Using the below code, I get the hovered over line to change style whilst fading out the other lines in that chart.

```
  // Fading and Selecting Lines
d3.selectAll('path.line.mainline')
    .on("mouseover", function(d) { 
    var HoveredLine = this;
     d3.selectAll('path.line.mainline').transition().duration(0)
       .style('opacity',function () {
       return (this === HoveredLine) ? 1.0 : 0.1;
    })
      .style('stroke-width',function () {
       return (this === HoveredLine) ? 4 : 2;
    })

;
})
```

This is achieved by giving the lines an `id` using `classed`.  Using a different id, the lines in the other chart are selected similarly.

What I want to achieve is a way that if the line of e.g. group A is highlighted in one chart, it is also highlighted in the other chart also (and all other non-selected lines are faded in all charts).  I thought maybe this could be done by getting the index of the selected line and somehow using that in the other chart.

Comment: Use classes, this is what they're for. You can select all of the lines with the given class and make your change.

Comment: @AJFarkas is it possible / how is it best to add classes to individual lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can solve it by having a single place where we handle `mouseover` and `mouseout` for both lines.

Primarily to avoid code repeat (DRY principle)

We will write mouse over and mouse out in a single place from where we can handle events in both svg.

So instead of attaching listeners individually like this

```
d3.selectAll('path.line.mainline')
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {
```

and

```
d3.selectAll('path.line.mainlinel')
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {
```

Do it like this:

```
  d3.selectAll('path.line')//register this to all paths
    .on("mouseover", function(d,i) {
```

Make use of filter to get the lines on which it is hovered.

```
  d3.selectAll('path.line').filter(function(d1) {
      return d.name == d1.name; all which have same name get it via filter
    })
    .style("opacity", 1)//show filtered links
    .style("stroke-width", 4);
```

Full method will be like this:

```
function doHover() {
  d3.selectAll('path.line')//register this to all paths
    .on("mouseover", function(d,i) {
      //first make all lines vanish
      d3.selectAll('path.line')
        .style("opacity", 0.1)
        .style("stroke-width", 2)
      //only show lines which have same name.
      d3.selectAll('path.line').filter(function(d1) {
          return d.name == d1.name
        })
        .style("opacity", 1)
        .style("stroke-width", 4);

      d3.select("div#chartw.container svg")
        .append("text")
        .attr("id", "cohorttext")
        .html("Cohort " + d.name)
        .attr("x", (width) / 1.2)
        .attr("y", margin.top * 1.5)
        .style("fill", color(d.name))
        .style("font-weight", "bold")
        .style("font-size", "18px");

      d3.select("div#chartw.container svg")
        .append("text")
        .attr("id", "cohorttextx")
        .html("Gini = " + giniw[i%giniw.length])//so that its always within the max length
        .attr("x", (width) / 1.2)
        .attr("y", 20 + margin.top * 1.5)
        .style("fill", color(d.name))
        .style("font-size", "14px");  



    d3.select("div#chartl.container svg")
        .append("text")
        .attr("id", "cohorttext")
        .text("Cohort " + d.name)
        .attr("x", (width) / 1.2)
        .attr("y", margin.top * 1.5)
        .style("fill", color(d.name))
        .style("font-weight", "bold")
        .style("font-size", "18px");


   d3.select("div#chartl.container svg")
        .append("text")
        .attr("id", "cohorttextx")
        .html("Gini = " + ginil[i%ginil.length])//so that its always within the max length
        .attr("x", (width) / 1.2)
        .attr("y", 20 + margin.top * 1.5)
        .style("fill", color(d.name))
        .style("font-size", "14px");    
    })
    .on("mouseout", function() {
      d3.selectAll('path.line')
        .style("opacity", 1)
        .style("stroke-width", 2);
      //selectALL because we are giving same id to both text in 2 svgs  
      d3.selectAll("#cohorttext").remove()
      d3.selectAll("#cohorttextx").remove()  

    })
}
```

Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/rOevvtZTsCGO9NVzZF2D?p=preview)

Please let me know if you have any queries on this.

Comment: thanks  - I'm going to try it out on a couple of other visualizations of the same multi-chart multi-line format. Looks great so far.

Comment: I *sort* of get the idea. Just checking in your code - it's ok to remove the `on.mouseover()` that occurs in the 'wins' section.It seems like maybe you just forgot to remove that - it's not actually doing anything ?

Comment: also, i'm not entirely sure why `giniw[i%giniw.length])` is needed over just `i`.  ? thanks

Comment: Yes!  it is ok to remove the on.mouseover() that occurs in the 'wins' section. That is my mistake you should remove it. This change `giniw[i%giniw.length])` is done so that giniw is always within the max limit of the array. I am taking a modulus here.

Comment: thanks - I get that now - it's because with the linked graphs, the `i`'s go outside the array. Nice idea!